# capturing dns packets using java

Tags: java, networking, dns, jpcap

I want to log the websites visited in a system. So i decided to record the packets send by the system. I am using Jpcap API. I am able to record a lot of packets. Now what i want to do is i want to filter only DNS packets. I think that will be able to log the websites.

I want a way to filter the DNS packets. How can I do it?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

i found it easy processing all the packets in port 53 and so i used this filter

> udp dst port 53

tanx jack for ur hint

Answer (score 2):

One uglier approach is to scan on port 53 for UDP. 
However, previous answer looks cleaner from implementation aspect.

Comment: is the port number the source port or the destination port

Comment: Well, as we are sending this packet to well-known port 53 of server. That means, destination port number. 
PS: You may want to check for TCP and UDP both.

Answer (score 0):

[Here](http://netresearch.ics.uci.edu/kfujii/jpcap/doc/tutorial/index.html#set) it says

> You can check the following homepage
>   for more details about filter
>   expression. Designing Capture Filters
>   for Ethereal/Wireshark

Thus, I believe

```
captor.setFilter("dns", true);
```

should work

Comment: its the exception that throws when i tried your solution

Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: Error occurred while compiling or setting filter: syntax error
        at jpcap.JpcapCaptor.setFilter(Native Method)
        at test1.JpcapTip.main(JpcapTip.java:25)
Java Result: 1